# Offsetting columns in Bootstrap v4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-4

What used to be:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-3"> ... </div>
</div>
```

Became:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2 offset-xs-3"> ... </div>
</div>
```

in Bootstrap v4 Alpha. Now, that I've updated the website to v4 Beta `offset-xs-3` doesn't seem to be working anymore: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns.

How do I offset by a specified amount of columns in v4 Beta?

https://codepen.io/Deka87/pen/prVLyE

Comment: Look at the documentation you linked to. _"we no longer have v3’s style of offset classes. Instead, use margin utilities like .mr-auto"_

Comment: What is your desired output on it?

Comment: What do you mean by "specified amount"? Set up a jsFiddle if you can, with an example. I believe the documentation you linked in pretty clear.

Comment: @DimitrisDamilos, included an example code in the questions. This is exactly what `offset-sm-x` and `col-sm-offset-x` did in previous versions.

Comment: @Turnip, this will align the col on the left side, please see an example in the question.

Comment: @RBCunhaDesign, I've added an example and a Codepen.

Comment: @sdvnksv, why in the world do you want to offset 3 columns? Is it to center something else?

Comment: @RBCunhaDesign, millions of use cases for that. Things are not always either in the center, or on the right or left sides. This is exactly why they had `col-sm-offset-X` or `offset-sm-X`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I know this is not pretty, but since Bootstrap v4-beta took the offsetting by number out of the game, you can add an empty column before and making it however many columns you want to offset the next one.

```css
[class*="col-"] {
  background-color: #eee;
}
.row {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      .col-sm-2 offseted by 3 columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Right, was hoping to avoid that and though I missed something. This saved my ass many times.

Comment: @sdvnksv i have not converted anything to BS v4-beta yet, but I do have projects that are on v4- alpha and also use the offset method. If i do find another way I'll come back here and share it. I guess the reason why they took it out is because a lot of people only used the offset class to center things on the screen.

Comment: Thanks! I have submitted an issue via Github as well.

Comment: Just got a reply that offsetting columns will be restored in Beta 2.

Comment: @sdvnksv, that is some good news!

Comment: @sdvnksv link to your Github issue please?

Comment: @jeff-h https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/23616

Comment: Update: This was fixed in the latest Beta.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need, https://jsfiddle.net/5L49z51y/1/?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2 ml-sm-auto mr-sm-auto"> Here </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, this aligns it in the center. I want it to move by two - three - four columns to the right depending on the case. If you've ever used `.col-sm-offset-X` or `offset-sm-X` you should have an idea of what I want.